# How to write an XML Schema (XSD) for this XML?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, xml-validation

**Rules for Schema:**

- four slam elements
- the score has four tie-break sets; the last set should cater for
  7-5 (as was the case in Australia that year).
- winner and runnerUp are strings; first letter is a capital letter,
  followed by lowercase letters
- surface is one of Clay, Rebound Ace, Grass or Hard Court
- name is one of Australia, French Open, Wimbledon or US Open
- two semiFinalists, both strings; first letter is a capital letter,
  followed by lowercase letters
- year is a proper schema year type (not string)

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Slams ...>
        <slam name="Australia" year="2012">
            <winner>Djokovic</winner>
            <runnerUp>Nadal</runnerUp>
            <score>5-76-46-26-77-5</score>
            <surface>Rebound Ace</surface>
            <semiFinalist>Federer</semiFinalist>
            <semiFinalist>Murray</semiFinalist>
        </slam>
        <slam name="French Open" year="2012">
            <winner>Nadal</winner>
            <runnerUp>Djokovic</runnerUp>
            <score>6-46-32-67-5</score>
            <surface>Clay</surface>
            <semiFinalist>Federer</semiFinalist>
            <semiFinalist>Ferrer</semiFinalist>
        </slam>
        <slam name="Wimbledon" year="2012">
            <winner>Federer</winner>
            <runnerUp>Murray</runnerUp>
            <score>4-67-56-36-4</score>
            <surface>Grass</surface>
            <semiFinalist>Djokovic</semiFinalist>
            <semiFinalist>Tsonga</semiFinalist>
        </slam>
        <slam name="US Open" year="2012">
            <winner>Murray</winner>
            <runnerUp>Djokovic</runnerUp>
            <score>7-67-52-63-66-2</score>
            <surface>Hard Court</surface>
            <semiFinalist>Berdych</semiFinalist>
            <semiFinalist>Ferrer</semiFinalist>
        </slam>
    </Slams>
```

### XSD

This is what I have got so far but I'm not sure if it is correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">



<xs:element name="Australia">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="winner" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="runnerUp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="score" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surface" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="French Open">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="winner" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="runnerUp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="score" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surface" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Wimbledon">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="winner" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="runnerUp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="score" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surface" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="US Open">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="winner" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="runnerUp" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="score" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="surface" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Are you looking to learn, or do you just wish someone would do this for you?

Comment: both I've tried to get my head around it all week and it has to be handed in tomorrow so this is my last resort

Comment: Show what you have and where you're stuck.  Then we can help with "both".

Comment: That is what I have got so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems to fix:**

**#1**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
  xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

to

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

**#2**

Define a single `slam` element, with an `name` attribute, not disparate elements for each such named possibility.  Also add a `year` attribute.

**#3**

Your XML (as far as you've shown) doesn't use namespaces, so remove that these lines from your XSD `xs:schema` element:

```
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
```

**#4**

Place `slam` element within `Slams` element declaration, and use `maxOccurs="unbounded"`.  Use `maxOccurs="2"` (or 3 or `unbounded`) for `semiFinalist` rather than repeating the element declaration in `slam`.

### Altogether:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="Slams">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="slam" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="winner" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="runnerUp" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="score" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="surface" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="semiFinalist" type="xs:string" 
                          maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="year" type="xs:integer"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This will get you an XSD that validates your XML.

Left as an exercise for the reader:  Tune it to meet the given **Rules for Schema**.

Answer (score 0):

Element names are the name of the tags : in your case 
You are confusing it with the value of the attribute name

Comment: so <xs:element name="Australia"> would actually be <xs:element name="slam"> ?